# password_verify dont match

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, password-hash

I'm using password_verify to match a password from user input and hash password from database.

This is the variable i use to get user input.

```
$current_password = $this->input->post('current_password');
```

And i use `row_array()` to get a row from user table. field password is varchar(256).

```
$data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
```

And then i use `var_dump` but its always return false

```
var_dump(password_verify($current_password, $data['user']['password']));
```

i don't know what's wrong with my code. I try to `var_dump()` the hash password from dtb and its exactly same.

```
var_dump($data['user']['password']);

// Output
string(60) "$2y$10$w4wKGfA/z76.mNkfgD5gfOcnNSzWGL06CxQuw/fhukIGdZtb1HXFm"

// Vardump user input
var_dump($current_password);

// Output
string(4) '1234'
```

The weirdest thing is, i try to hash the input.

```
$current_password = 1234;
$hash = password_hash($current_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
var_dump($hash);

// Output
string(60) "$2y$10$jRhdd.8Wse/fQ5A0mXtZfe9.n6JPeEpsLd8r06/bvL6MwVLVLbSZC"
```

It is totally different with the hash password from database, but how it can be? I use this password (1234) to login and it's working, login is use password_verify too.

Note: I use `trim` in `form_validation` for all of my password input, so there's no space in the beginning and the end of user input. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `password_hash()` will always generate a new salt, so the two hash strings from separate calls will never match. Show us the code that produces the hash, as that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: use static values like this to test `$data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => 'example@email'])->row_array();` then `var_dump($data['user']);`

Comment: @OmarAbbas 
ouput

`array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(23) "Elwin Musadi Bessiesura" ["email"]=> string(21) "elwinmusadi@gmail.com" ["image"]=> string(7) "aaa.gif" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$w4wKGfA/z76.mNkfgD5gfOcnNSzWGL06CxQuw/fhukIGdZtb1HXFm" ["role_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["date_created"]=> string(10) "1568103864" }`

Comment: now this `var_dump(password_verify($current_password, $data['user']['password']));` should return true for a password match

Comment: @OmarAbbas its still return false :'(
`bool(false)`

Comment: that means your password don't match, create a hash for a new password and then use that same password in `password_verify('password', 'hash')`

Comment: I got trapped by this too. It creates a new salt for each call, so you need to use password_verify with typed password and hash saved on database: `password_verify('foo', password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT))`

Comment: `password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT) !== password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` this is true besides being conter intuition it safer

Comment: All I can suggest is outputting the hash that is generated and compare with what's in the db to make sure it is stored correctly.

Comment: Try running the stored password through [password_get_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php) and see if the return makes any sense.